# "bash: rails: command not found" on heroku even though rails is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I created a new heroku app, pushed the code, it was recognized as a rails app, and heroku started running the migrations. This lead to an error, and so I tried to run:

```
heroku run rails db:reset --remote staging
```

However, even though rails was obviously installed, I got this error:

```
bash: rails: command not found
```

I also tried replacing rails with `/app/bin/rails`, which didn't work either.

Comment: Can you share the whole command?

Comment: @dev-cc The full command is heroku run rails db:reset --remote staging

Comment: Try 'heroku run bundle exec rails db:reset --remote staging'

Comment: @Pablo Leads to: ```bash: bundle: command not found```

Comment: @fajiweh Do you do any success deploy? Try to upload a minior version of the app without these errors.